# Power Apps :I need onstart action for datacardvalue. How to implement it differently?

Tags: action, onchange, key-value, powerapps

I need to use the value of a datacard for checking if it matches a global variable.

The problem is that the only actions that I can use is onselect (but the item is a card only for reading and can not be selected or edited) and onchange. So I used the second option (at least that works) but not if I click for first time. I need to first open another request to read and then select again the one that I need to change the field and enable the onchange action code I have written.

Is there any way to set like a value that is not appropriate and that it will change inevitably when I open the request for reading on first attempt? Setting a default value is not possible either as it has errors.

Answer (score 0):

I just added the code after ; on the "on select" field of the button that navigated me on the reading the request page. So the global variable was set before actually opening the request to read.